# Why should I use JWT and not a simple hashed token

Tags: php, jwt

What is the need for JWT if no sensitive information will be shared?

I could create a token column, store it in db and recover it, to cross verify the token and then get the user details.

The custom generated token can be hashed with a key so it's not decoded. When it's so simple, why to use a complicated JWT kind, that has information?

Comment: Your intuition is correct, in most cases you should just use a simple random string. (No need to hash a token)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> What is the need for JWT as there shall be no sensitive information shared?

A subject with a private id, the expiration date, or the issuer cannot be considered sensitive in most cases. And a token must be kept private between both parties since possession is the proof-of-authentication.

In any case, JWT content can be encrypted using JWE.

> The custom generated token can be hashed with a key so its not decoded. When its so simple, why to use a complicated JWT kind, that has information.

JWT, compared with an opaque token system, has some advantages:

- no need of server storage for tokens
- tokens have an expiration date
- share information securely between parties.

And drawbacks...

- No revocation mechanism. It is not recommended to set a blacklist because it breaks JWT statelessness
- Increases token size